# Cts search slow for one or two characters

Tags: performance, xquery, marklogic

I have a query for fetching autosuggest from xml, it works fine for 3 or more characters.. but is extremely slow for 1 or 2 characters..

Here's the xquery which I'm using, any correction would be appreciated..

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare default function namespace "local";
declare default collation "http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1";
declare variable $search-term := xdmp:get-request-field("query", "b");

declare function getWildCardedTerm($term as xs:string) as xs:string*{
    (fn:concat($search-term, "*"),fn:concat("* ",$search-term))
};

let $terms := getWildCardedTerm($search-term)

let $values := cts:search(//searchLabel,cts:and-query((cts:collection-query(("/collections/autosuggest")), cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("suggestion"),$terms))) )

let $suggestionsOrderedByLength := for $value in $values
order by fn:string-length($value//altLabel/text()), $value/altLabel/text()
return $value

return <suggestions>{$suggestionsOrderedByLength[1 to 10]}</suggestions>
```

Is there a way where to sort during search??

Answer (score 2):

The [Search Developer's Guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/wildcard) recommends combining the `trailing wildcard searches` with a `word lexicon`. You also have `three/two/one character searches` options you may not have enabled yet, but they will require substantial extra disk space.

But I'm afraid that MarkLogic indexes and lexicons are not particularly optimized for this use case. You can get `frequency-order` and `item-order` values directly from range indexes using [`cts:values`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:values), but not values ordered by length. If it would, you could have used that with a [`cts:index-order`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:index-order) to apply sorting to your `cts:search`.

I would recommend taking a look at [`cts:value-match`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-match) though, and apply that to your `suggestion` element. It will only require a range index, and no further settings. It will also not pull actual fragments from disk like `cts:search`, and run from in-memory data entirely. That will likely be faster..

HTH!

Comment: But the results that I want should be sorted by length in ascending order, how can I achieve that using cts:value-match?

Comment: Like you do now, using a FLWOR statement around `cts:value-match`. So, you essentially only replace `cts:search` with `cts:value-match`..